# Create an own Color Dialog

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, colors, colordialog

I want to create a custom `ColorDialog` in C# - what is the best way to do it?
I would like to have the dialog a bit bigger but the dialog should also contain the basic colors and also this color pipette, where you can click in an area and use that color then.

But is there also a way to do it by code (without the built-in graphics editor in VS2012)?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is an entire [magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164113.aspx) dedicated to creating your own color dialogs.  Surely you can find inspiration from that.

Comment: To get you started, I've previously answered a question on how to create a color wheel, see code along a screenshot : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10305050/361899. Here a more complex/PhotoShop-like : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35436/Adobe-Color-Picker-Clone. (there are many examples at CodeProject : http://www.codeproject.com/search.aspx?q=color+picker)

Comment: To add to the great number of pickers, here is a [screenshot](http://i58.tinypic.com/1qlix4.jpg) of one I wrote last week. It was inspired by the one in Kai's PowerTools Fractal Explorer and originally works by sweeping from the upper Hue-Saturation-Panel down to the Brightness Panel. To make it rich in the lower half I include a glimpse of the gradient builder, which is modelled after the Photoshop gradient tool.